# Swipe or Slider with Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, swipe, slide

I am trying to get either the Brad Birdsall swipe.js or the Chris Ferdinandi slider.js to work with Windows Phone 8.  Right now it does nothing whenever I attempt to swipe.  It works fine on iPhone and Droid.

https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe

http://cferdinandi.github.io/slider/

Comment: You mean viewing page using Windows Phone 8 IE10?

Comment: Yes.  Windows Phone 8, IE10

Comment: it used to work fine before the Cyan update, but now with the swipe from left to right forces the browser go back to the previous page... there must be some touch events changes that do affect the swipe.. having said that, I found that the owl swipe (jquery plugin) works fine!